# Finding most recent payment for each customer in a python dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a fund raising churn prediction problem. There is a payment table which list payments made by donors on different times. I need to find most recent payment made by each donor. Following is the snapshot of data. Here PAMT is the payment ; EXTRELNO is the donor code, PID is the unique payment id; PAYTYPECD is the type of payment (bank, permanent order etc.); STATUS is status of payment (refund, normal payment, correction , recall)

```
        PID          PDATE     PAMT    EXTRELNO PAYTYPECD   STATUS
    0   38.0      1993-12-31    9.57    0000019         X        CO
   1    39.0      1993-12-31    41.32   0000020        X         CO
   2    40.0       1993-12-31   13.10   0000020         X       CO
   3    54091.0    1994-01-01   2.02    0000020        X        CO
   4    104480.0    1994-05-19  0.50    0000020         D       OK
```

1. I want to find most recent payment made by each donor.
2. Frequency of donation
3. How can I find frequency of each type of payment & status.

I have tried finding out most  recent date on which payment is made.

```
df_pay.groupby('EXTRELNO').apply(lambda x: x['PDATE'].max()).reset_index()
```

But how to find payment made on that date. Pls help with this and other questions too

Answer (score 0):

1- a solution could be :

```
for g,f in df_pay.groupby('EXTRELNO'):
    print(f[f['PDATE'] == f['PDATE'].max()])
```

2- depends on what is meant by frequency but could be :

```
 df_pay.groupby(['PDATE'])['PID'].count()
```

3- a small adjustment :

```
df_pay.groupby(['PAYTYPECD','STATUS','PDATE'])['PID'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!   Question 2: I need To find how many number of times a donor has made the payment.. Please suggest how to do it. Is there any way we can find out length of each group ; if i groupby on 'EXTRELNO'

Comment: I guess agg is what you are looking for with a dictionary of column/function :
`df_pay.groupby('EXTRELNO').agg({"EXTRELNO":"count","PAMT":"sum"})`
please mark the solution if you got it solved

Comment: Thanks.. It worked, Though I tried with a different way and that too worked as well.    `g=df_pay.groupby('EXTRELNO')
g.size()
frq=pd.DataFrame(g.size(),columns=['Frequency'])`

Comment: Also , One more thing I need to calculate: I need to find out  **Recency** (how many days since last transaction).

Answer (score 0):

1- Finding most recent transaction for each donor

```
pd.DataFrame(df_pay.groupby('EXTRELNO').apply(lambda x: x['PDATE'].max()),columns=['recent_date'])
```

One more way of doing this

```
df_pay.sort_values(ascending=0, by='PDATE').groupby('EXTRELNO')['PDATE'].nth(0)
```